# Are closure of open subsets of [0, 1] “almost open”?

Tags: general-topology, lebesgue-measure

This might sound a bit weird, but given any open subset $O$ of $[0, 1]$, is it necessarily true that the closure of $O$ is “almost open” under the Lebesgue measure, in the sense that there exists an open subset $U$ which equals $ \bar{O}$ up to a null set? This holds for all intervals, hence also for all finite unions of intervals. It also holds for open dense sets. I feel like it shouldn’t be true in general but I couldn’t find a counterexample. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $G$ is open it is a countable union of disjoint intervals.  Then its boundary points are the endpoints of these intervals, so countable. So your open subset $U$ can be equal to $G$ itself; it is equal to $\bar U$ except for the set of boundary points, which is countable and therefore has null Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @MJD: The boundary can be much larger than just the endpoints of the intervals; for instance, consider the complement of the Cantor set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $K\subset[0,1]$ be a fat Cantor set, whose complement is a disjoint union of open intervals $I_n$.  Take a closed interval $J_n\subset I_n$ for each $n$ and let $O=\bigcup_n I_n\setminus J_n$.  Note that $\overline{O}$ contains all of $K$.

Now suppose $U$ is an open set which is equal to $\overline{O}$ up to a null set.  In particular, since $K$ has positive measure, this means $U$ must contain some point of $K$.  But every open interval around a point of $K$ contains the entirety of some interval $I_n$, so $U$ contains some $I_n$.  Since $\overline{O}$ does not contain almost all of any $I_n$ (it is missing the entire interior of $J_n$), this is a contradiction.